# Agregate nested list with Stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

Let's say I have a `Shelf` class and each `Shelf` has multiple `Book`s.

```
public class Shelf{
   private String shelfCode;
   private ArrayList<Book> books; //add getters, setters etc.
}

public class Book{
  private String title;
}
```

Now, let's say from some method I have a `List` of `Shelf`s, each containing some books. How do I use `stream` to collect all the books to this list?

```
List<Shelf> shelves = new ArrayList<Shelf>();

Shelf s1 = new Shelf();
s1.add(new Book("book1"));
s1.add(new Book("book2"));

Shelf s2 = new Shelf();
s1.add(new Book("book3"));
s1.add(new Book("book4"));

shelves.add(s1);
shelves.add(s2);

List<Book> booksInLibrary = //??
```

I'm thinking something like

```
List<Book> booksInLibrary = 
      shelves.stream()
             .map(s -> s.getBooks())
             .forEach(booksInLibrary.addall(books));
```

but it doesn't seem to work, throwing a compilation error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `flatMap` for this

```
shelves.stream()
       .flatMap(s -> s.getBooks().stream())
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The streaming process is quite simple : `s -> s.getBooks().stream()` makes a stream for each book on each shelf, `flatMap` flattens everything, and `collect(Collectors.toList())` stores the result in a list.

Comment: Indeed, any time you're thinking of using `forEach()` on a stream, take a step back and ask yourself "is this really the best approach?". Then answer yourself with "ah, of course not".

Comment: I think you need to add a `map` step to your example to get the books property of the Shelf object

Comment: Yep, it should be `flatMap(s -> s.getBooks().stream())`

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-flatmap-example/ more great examples and good explanations of how flatMap  works

Comment: yet a slightly different approach using method references -->  `shelves.stream().map(Shelf::getBooks).flatMap(List::stream)
       .collect(Collectors.toList());`